# Alternative for Node Gallery in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, media

Will I be able to have show an image gallery for a multiple value image field on the node display in drupal 7 with some alternative module?

http://drupal.org/project/node_gallery is only available for drupal 6

that´s anoying, every alternative that I´ve found is eighter abandoned or only for D6

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking for recommendations or suggestions on books, tools, modules, themes, distributions, tutorials, or other off-site resources.

Answer (score 1):

[Field slideshow](http://drupal.org/project/field_slideshow) is a good alternative.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon your from two year question looking for an alternative for Node Gallery – and even though I don't know if your question is still valid, but at least I wanted to let you know a beta3 version of Node Gallery is available for dp7:

https://drupal.org/project/node_gallery

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple other image gallery modules for Drupal 7.

[Media Gallery](http://drupal.org/project/media_gallery)

[Gallery Formatter](http://drupal.org/project/galleryformatter)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Gallery Formatter](http://drupal.org/project/galleryformatter) and [Multiupload Imagefield Widget](http://drupal.org/project/multiupload_imagefield_widget) module to get your result.